# How to access class path resource from MuleStudio and Mule Maven Standalone?

Tags: maven, groovy, mule, mule-studio

How do you access a class path resource from src/main/resources with a Groovy script?  The following script works in MuleStudio, but does not work in Mule Maven standalone.  Is there a way to write the script where it can pull the correct resource from MuleStudio and Mule Maven standalone?

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Script">
    <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
        def command = "src/main/resources/shellscript/shellscriptfile.sh"
        def cmd = command.execute()
        cmd.waitFor()]]>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Comment: The problem is that in MuleStudio the class path directory is projectDir/classes/src/main/resources/shellscript, but in Standalone the build has the class path as apps/projectDir/classes/shellscript.  Is there a way to write a Groovy script that can automatically determine what the application home directory is that contains the classes folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the command as a classpath resource instead of trying to build a path that works in all cases:

```
def command = this.getClass().getResource('/shellscript/shellscriptfile.sh').path
def cmd = command.execute()
cmd.waitFor()
```

Comment: Thanks David.  One thing to add.  Groovy reads it as a URL object and tries to run execute() method onto which doesn't exist.  Just needed to add .getPath() at the end to make it an executable shell script command.

`def command = this.getClass().getResource('/scripts/RequestReturnBatch.sh').getPath()`
`def cmd = command.execute()`
`cmd.waitFor()]]>`